# How can I randomly generate a pair of floats in Elm?

Tags: random, elm

I am trying to create a `Random.Generator (Float, Float)` where the first `Float` is in some range say `0.0` `1000.0` and the second between `0.0` and the first value.

Example of valid values: `(12.0, 5.0)`
Invalid: `(303.0, 800.0)`

I looked over code in [Random.Extra](https://github.com/elm-community/elm-random-extra/blob/1.0.1/src/Random/Array.elm#L37) module but I wasn't able to find my way around.

The example bellow don't even compile. :)

```
tuple = 
  let range = float 0.0 500.0
  in flatMap (\max -> (max, float 0.0 max)) range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the generator code:

```
floatTuple : Random.Generator (Float, Float)
floatTuple =
    Random.float 0.0 1000.0 
    `Random.andThen`
    (\val1 -> Random.map ((,) val1) (Random.float 0 val1))
```

And here is how you can use it (in 0.17):

```
(tuple, nextSeed) = Random.step floatTuple initialSeed
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Random.andThen`

Here is a full working example (you can copy&paste it in http://elm-lang.org/try)

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as App

import Random exposing (Generator, generate, float, map, andThen) 
import Time exposing (every, second) 

myPair : Float -> Float -> Generator (Float, Float) 
myPair min max =
  let 
    range = float min max 
  in 
    range 
    `andThen` (\f -> map ((,) f) (float min f)) 


type Msg = Request | Update (Float, Float) 

update msg model = 
  case msg of 
    Request -> model ! [generate Update (myPair 0 1000)]
    Update pair -> pair ! []


view model = text (toString model) 


main =
  App.program 
    { init = (0,0) ! []
    , update = update 
    , view = view 
    , subscriptions = (\_ -> every (2*second) (always Request))
    }
```